# php/mysql returns all data from table or none at all

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on finishing off an assessment for college but it has been driving me nuts for days and i finally found an awesome guide for php/mysql etc.

What i am trying to do is display a students details from a database using their student number to fetch the data. after following the info i found i managed to get rid of all the error messages but now when i run the site to display the required info i get nothing.

Understandably i can retrieve all the data from the table using the select * command but it then returns no data at all as soon as i change it to a specific command:

```
$database="college";
$student_number="student_number";

mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'root', ''); 

$db_found = mysql_select_db($database);

if($db_found)
{
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM student where student_number = '$student_number'  ";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $db_field['student_number']."<BR>";
        echo $db_field['title']."<BR>";
        echo $db_field['forename']."<BR>";
        echo $db_field['surname']."<BR>";
        echo $db_field['gender']."<BR>";
        echo $db_field['date_of_birth']."<BR>";
        echo $db_field['dept_number']."<BR>";
        echo $db_field['course_number']."<BR>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo"Database not found";
}
```

Any help, advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: there are no students matching that student number.

Comment: $student_number="student_number"; is this by mistake as it's not a number?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: What is the value of $student number?

Comment: Do you get an mysql error? Tip: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: What @pascalvgemert said. Check the mysql_error() and then if there is no error proceed to check the number of rows returned using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

It may be that there are no results in the table matching the criteria after all :)

Comment: Could you please add the schema of your table `student` ?

Comment: Assuming `student_number` is an `INT` field, then it shouldn't be enclosed in single quotes. 
`$SQL = "SELECT * FROM student where student_number = $student_number  ";`

Comment: You should also be way more careful with data you haven't sanitized before putting it into a SQL query. Use a prepared statement to help deal with that problem. Also, I'm sure someone will say it eventually, you should move to using mysqli as mysql_* will be deprecated.

Comment: Wow thanks for all the quick replies. The student number is a varchar which is entered into a form on the previous page i'm currently looking at that to see if the issue lies there. unfortunately this is a college assessment so I have been told I have to use this format. I'm also attempting mysql_error().

Answer (score 0):

Is student number an integer? If so, having quotes around it could be the problem. Because other than that it looks like it should work fine :S (even so, I think it should work fine with quotes).

Otherwise, if student number is a varchar/text data type, what happens when you use LIKE instead of = ? . Another option would be

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE STRCMP('$student_number', student_number) <> 0

//or this:
SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_number IN ('$student_number')
```

Though even if it's a text field, = should work, I think, I have not been using MySQL for a long time.

Your problem could also be in your $student_number variable, you could echo $SQL to see what it is resolving to.

Also, $db_field should probably be $db_row or $db_record.

Comment: the student number is a string, i said varcher in my other comment but i am now pretty sure string is right. Sorry i'm half asleep been working on this forever it seems. I have attempted the things you suggested here but it still keeps coming up with no information. The student number is being sent from a simple form on the previous page but the more i think about it the more i think that's the issue i just cant see it.

Comment: You should echo $student_number or $SQL to the page to see what it's set to. My guess is that $student_number will be null.

Actually, I see you have edited your question. Great, it's working now :)

But, be sure to sanitize the input to protect from SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Ok totally kicking myself here i had simply missed out $_POST when declaring the variable, I had tried, it didnt work i obviously didnt think the change the quotations.

Thank you so much for your answers i am sure i will be back at some point in the next few days to pick your brains further